# Vim abbreviations with accented characters not completely replacing text

Tags: vim, non-ascii-characters

My Vim abbreviations are not working when I use Spanish accents or characters. I have in my `.vimrc` the following:

```
iab maniana mañana
iab habia había
```

But when I hit <kbd>Space</kbd> after typing for instance "habia," I only get "habí."

My `iskeywords` are set as:

```
set iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255,:,#
```

**Edit:** the command `:verbose iab habia` returns `i habia hab<ed>a` and the command `:verbose iab maniana` returns `i maniana ma<f1>ana`.

Comment: What is output of `:set encoding?`

Comment: The outputs is: utf-8

Comment: in your terminal, execute `vim --version|grep -Eo ".multi_\w+"` what is the output?

Comment: @Kent I'm using Gvim under Windows, so how can I execute that?

Comment: @petobens then in your vim, type `:version` see if you have `+multi_byte +multi_lang`

Comment: @Kent Yes, I have both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a simple encoding problem. (Solution at the bottom.)

It seems that when `:iab maniana mañana` is executed, `ñ` is interpreted in Latin 1 encoding, where it is one byte in size and has the value `0x00f1`:

```
ñ (Latin 1):    11110001
```

When you *use* the abbreviation, however, you have somehow switched to UTF-8 encoding.

Vim just inserts the bytes you have stored in the right-hand side: `11110001`. But in UTF-8 `ñ` has a different representation – in fact, `11110001` is an invalid UTF-8 byte (shown as `<f1>`) and that's why the expansion stops. Just to illustrate the point, these are the UTF-8 bytes for `ñ`:

```
ñ (UTF-8):      11000011 10110001
                      ^^   ^^^^^^
```

Incidentally, *ñ* has the Unicode *codepoint* `0x00f1`, and you can actually see it encoded in the two bytes shown above.

Ok, you ask, but what does it mean?!

It means that you should check your vimrc and make sure `:set encoding=utf-8` comes before the abbreviation.

Comment: After reading your answer I scanned through my `vimrc` file and found the line `scriptencoding utf-8` just before `set encoding=utf8`. I don't know why I had it there (probably the first time I installed Vim for some reason the `vimrc` file didn't display accented characters and I must've added that line). Commenting it out seems to solve the problem.